# jQuery html css slidetoggle effect

Tags: jquery, html, css, web

I'm trying to make a movie booking system website which also has info on movies. I want to implement a mechanism where when a user clicks on the poster of a particular movie, its info(description and cast) shows up and slides down. I have achieved this. But the problem I'm having is, when a description of a particular movie slides downwards, every other movie poster in the same row slide down with it. What I want is for every other element to remain static.

**Here is my HTML code:**

```
    <div class="contents">
    <table id="movies">
        <tr>
            <td class="Horror"><img id="Image1" src="<?php echo "$image_1"; ?>" width=250 height=400> <p><?php echo "Name: $name_1";?></p>
                                                                                                <p class="description" id="desc1"><?php echo "<span>Description:</span> $description_1"?>
                                                                                                <p class="cast" id="cast1"> <?php echo "<span>Cast:</span> $cast_1" ?></p></td>
            <td class="Action"><img id="Image2" src="<?php echo "$image_2"; ?>" width=250 height=400> <p><?php echo "Name: $name_2";?></p>
                                                                                            <p class="description" id="desc2"><?php echo "<span>Description:</span> $description_2"?>
                                                                                            <p class="cast" id="cast2"> <?php echo "<span>Cast:</span> $cast_2" ?></p></td>
            <td class="Action"><img id="Image3" src="<?php echo "$image_3"; ?>" width=250 height=400> <p><?php echo "$name_3";?></p>
                                                                                            <p class="description" id="desc3"><?php echo "<span>Description:</span> $description_3"?>
                                                                                            <p class="cast" id="cast3"> <?php echo "<span>Cast:</span>$cast_3" ?></p></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td class="Action"><img id="Image4" src="<?php echo "$image_4"; ?>" width=250 height=400> <p><?php echo "Name: $name_4";?></p>
                                                                                            <p class="description" id="desc4"><?php echo "<span>Description:</span> $description_4"?>
                                                                                            <p class="cast" id="cast4"> <?php echo "<span>Cast:</span> $cast_4" ?></p></td>
            <td class="Horror"><img id="Image5" src="<?php echo "$image_5"; ?>" width=250 height=400> <p><?php echo "Name: $name_5";?></p>
                                                                                            <p class="description" id="desc5"><?php echo "<span>Description:</span> $description_5"?>
                                                                                            <p class="cast" id="cast5"> <?php echo "<span>Cast:</span> $cast_5" ?></p></td>
            <td class="Comedy"><img id="Image6" src="<?php echo "$image_6"; ?>" width=250 height=400> <p><?php echo "Name: $name_6";?></p>
                                                                                            <p class="description" id="desc6"><?php echo "<span>Description:</span> $description_6"?>
                                                                                            <p class="cast" id="cast6"> <?php echo "<span>Cast:</span> $cast_6" ?></p></td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</div>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/show.js"></script>
```

**And this is my CSS:**

```
    td .description{

display:none;
padding:40px;
/*background-image: url('Images/desc_back.jpg');*/
background-color: rgba(230, 230, 239, 0.3);
color:#222;
position:relative;
right:-120px;
top:-290px;
/*margin:0, auto;*/
border: 3px solid transparent;
border-radius: 10px;
overflow:hidden;
}

    td .cast {
display:none;
/*background-color: rgba(34, 34, 34, 0.4);
color:#f3f2f1;*/
background-color: rgba(230, 230, 239, 0.3);
color:#222;
position:relative;
right:-120px;
top:-290px;

border: 3px solid transparent;
border-radius: 10px;
}
    span{
font-size:16px;
font-weight: bold;
text-decoration: underline;
}
```

**and my jQuery:**

```
    $('document').ready(function(){
var count=1;

    $('#Image1').click(function(){
if(count === 1){
    $('#desc1').slideToggle('slow');
    $('#cast1').slideToggle('slow');
     count=0;
}
else{
    $('#cast1').slideToggle('fast');
    $('#desc1').slideToggle('fast');
     count=1;
}
});
    $('#Image2').click(function(){
if(count === 1){
    $('#desc2').slideToggle('slow');
    $('#cast2').slideToggle('slow');
     count=0;
}
else{
    $('#cast2').slideToggle('fast');
    $('#desc2').slideToggle('fast');
     count=1;
}
});
    $('#Image3').click(function(){
if(count === 1){
    $('#desc3').slideToggle('slow');
    $('#cast3').slideToggle('slow');
     count=0;
}
else{
    $('#cast3').slideToggle('fast');
    $('#desc3').slideToggle('fast');
     count=1;
}
 });
    $('#Image4').click(function(){
if(count === 1){
    $('#desc4').slideToggle('slow');
    $('#cast4').slideToggle('slow');
     count=0;
}
else{
    $('#cast4').slideToggle('fast');
    $('#desc4').slideToggle('fast');
     count=1;
}
});
    $('#Image5').click(function(){
if(count === 1){
    $('#desc5').slideToggle('slow');
    $('#cast5').slideToggle('slow');
     count=0;
}
else{
    $('#cast5').slideToggle('fast');
    $('#desc5').slideToggle('fast');
     count=1;
}
});
    $('#Image6').click(function(){
if(count === 1){
    $('#desc6').slideToggle('slow');
    $('#cast6').slideToggle('slow');
     count=0;
}
else{
    $('#cast6').slideToggle('fast');
    $('#desc6').slideToggle('fast');
     count=1;
}
});
});
```

What I want to achieve is only want my description and cast to slide and keep everything else fixed. Really appreciate any help I get.

Comment: What's with the `count`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd say forget about tables, ids, counters, if...else statements. This problem is easier than what you're thinking. The key is to use classes and `this`.

Check out the **[demo](http://jsbin.com/avixob/6)**.

First create *proper* markup. You could change the paragraph with another div if necessary, the point is *not* use tables for this because they're probably not necessary and it complicates things for no reason.

```
<div class="movie">
  <img src="http://placekitten.com/270/390"/>
  <p>
    <strong>Title</strong>
    <span>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet...</span>
  </p>
</div>
```

Then position everything with css. If you use `border-box` it will be easier to adjust because you don't have to worry about widths.

```
* {
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
.movie { 
  width: 270px;
  height: 390px;
  position: relative;
  cursor: pointer;
}
.movie strong {
  display: block;
  font-size: 20px;
}
.movie p {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  padding: 1em;
  margin: 0;
  width: 100%;
  background: rgba(255,255,0,.8);
  display: none;
}
```

And finally, all you need is *one* line of jQuery:

```
$('.movie').click(function() { $('p', this).slideToggle(); });
```

Comment: Worked perfectly, Thank you so much

Answer (score 1):

You can do like this:

```
$('[id^="Image"]').each(function() {
    $(this).click(function() {
        if(count === 1){
            $(this).siblings('.description').slideToggle('slow');
            $(this).siblings('.cast').slideToggle('slow');
            count=0;
        }
        else{
            $(this).siblings('.description').slideToggle('fast');
            $(this).siblings('.cast').slideToggle('fast');
            count=1;
        }
    });
})
```